# View Web Analytics reports in SharePoint Foundation 2010 Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to look at Web Analytics reports older than 30 days in SharePoint Foundation 2010. According to [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663487.aspx), I should be able to:

1. Log onto Central Administration as a member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
2. In Central Administration, on the Home page, click Monitoring.
3. On the Monitoring page, in the Reporting section, click View Web Analytics reports.

Steps 1 and 2 are fine, but in step 3, I don't see an option under Reporting for View Web Analytics reports.

Could this be a permissions issue? I think I have maximum permissions, and am a member of the "Farm Administrators" group.

Is viewing reports older than 30 days not available in Foundation?

I know that the reports are running, because I can view reports up to 30 days old by going to the site itself, then Site Settings > Site Web Analytics reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official feature comparison page](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx), **Web Analytics** feature is only available in Standard and Enterprise editions. The page you are referencing also indicates this is a server feature not available in Foundation edition.

Comment: Thanks for that link. The reports actually are available via the site itself for the past 30 days, but I guess they disable them if it is longer ago than 30 days in Foundation! Kind of annoying. Maybe I could go into the database directly and see if I can pull the info that way. Or just screencap the reports manually every 30 days.

Comment: There is a reporting database in Server edition, take look and maybe you could offload data to a different database if it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

dbo.RequestUsage, which contains this data is a queryable view.  Potentially you could run a nightly  job to copy the day's data to an archive in another location.